# IP conflict on internal network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ip

I have a netgate 8100 that rolls out my DHCP numbers and some of my workstations that have static and most are DHCP. I have one workstation that is reporting an IP conflict and can not find the conflicting device. My question is how can I find the dup IP numbers on my network and release or resolve the conflict without going to each workstation or device?

Comment: Exactly *how many* devices are on your network? To narrow it down, it's probably one of your static and one of your dynamic hosts. I would take the static IP ranges out of your dhcp scope, but keep them in the same subnet.

Comment: I have 46 devices on my ip range.

Comment: I don't have control of the range on the netgate device.

Comment: I just need to find the existing .223 address and remove it so I can assign it to the needed workstation

Answer (score 1):

How to find the duplicate IP number is easy. Look at the IP of the workstation which is complaining. That should be the same IP as something else already is using.

If you have managed switches you can then log into them and see which port is connected to that IP. How you do that precisely depends on your switch.  Usually a managed switch has a command to list IPs of MAC addresses per port.

If you have a documentation listing the specs of each computer (e.g. if you work in IT at a firm which uses management software) you can look up which device this MAC belong to.

Finally, if you have neither (no docs, and only unmanaged dumb switches) then do the following: 1) Leave the workstation with the duplicate IP off the network. 2) Set up another computer to send message to the computer with the rogue IP. If you have a Unix like OS then `ping -a` (audible ping) might come in handy.  3). Unplug cables one by one until the beeping or the ICMP echo request answers stop.

Comment: I don't have a UNIX box to ping with, can I do the same with a win 7 or XP unit

Comment: Note that the `-a` flag work on windows, but does something different. (Normal behaviour is the beep).

Comment: so...cmd line would look like this??

Comment: ping 10.33.160.223 -a

Comment: how do I make it run a continous ping

Comment: On windows: `ping -t IP.to.ping.to`.

Comment: @BobGregg Something else comes to mind: If the 2nd machine is a Windows box, use a remote shutdown command and see what happens. I suppose you could do the same thing if a Unix/Mac box has remote support and/or ssh turned on.

Comment: Or even change the IP on the other box. :-)